# missing appended elements on window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, append

I have a simple form in my html page.

User can add elements in my form via append jquery function. It works fine, but if the form is submited and user is redirected to another page and goes back via `window.history.back()`, appended elements are missing.

Can you help me, how to save the page state before submit form to prevent missing appended elements?

Comment: have a look at `history.pushState`

Comment: You can save the state with `sessionStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(state))` and get it with `let state = sessionStorage.getItem("state");`.

Comment: Can you please more specify these answers? History.pushState only save URL to the history and JSON.stringify(state) throws error "state is not defined"

Comment: The description of the tag `history` starts with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" (yes, in CAPITALS for CLARITY). So don't use it.